# How to create a nested bulleted list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem, bulletedlist

I am using ASP.net with C# and I would like to have a list that i can code dynamically to look like somewhat this:

- Menu Item A

  - Sub Menu Link 1
  - Sub Menu Link 2
  - Sub Menu Link 3

so far i have managed to create the first past by doing this:

```
BulletedList MainUl = new BulletedList();
MainUl.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink;
ListItem item = new ListItem("Menu Item A", "http://www.google.com");
MainUl.Items.Add(item);            
panel.Controls.Add(MainUl);
```

The problem is i do not know how to nest the other sub items under the main "Menu Item A"

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `DataControl` ( DataList, Repeater, GridView) with `BulletedList`. You should try [Menu or TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item A" Value="0">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu Link 1" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu Link 2" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu Link 3" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Or this code

```
<asp:TreeView ID="MyTreeView" Runat="server">
  <Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0" Expanded="True" Text="Menu Item A">
      <asp:TreeNode Text="Sub Menu Link 1" Value="1" />
      <asp:TreeNode Text="Sub Menu Link 2" Value="2" />
      <asp:TreeNode Text="Sub Menu Link 3" Value="3" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
  </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: How to make each menu item a link?

Answer (score 0):

Use Tree view

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 TreeNode pn = new TreeNode("Menu Item A");
     TreeNode cn1 = new TreeNode("<a href='http://www.google.com.pk/' >Sub Menu Link 1</a>");
    TreeNode cn2 = new TreeNode("<a href='http://www.google.com.pk/' >Sub Menu Link 2</a>");
    TreeNode cn3 = new TreeNode("<a href='http://www.google.com.pk/' >Sub Menu Link 3</a>");

    TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    tv.Nodes.Add(pn);

    tv.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(cn1);
    tv.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(cn2);
    tv.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(cn3);        

    panel.Controls.Add(tv);
 }
```

Output:

```
Menu Item A
Sub Menu Link 1
Sub Menu Link 2
Sub Menu Link 3
```