# How to add second level bulleted list in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following HTML code which I am trying to convert to ASP.net control:

```
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='about_us.aspx'>ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="mission.aspx">MISSION</a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>LEADERSHIP</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>President</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Medical Director</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Board of Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Key Administrators</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='history.aspx'>HISTORY</a></li>
    <li><a href='community_support.aspx'>COMMUNITY SUPPORT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I converted it to ASP.net like this:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="bListMenu" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
    <asp:ListItem class="active" Value="about_us.aspx">ABOUT US</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="mission.aspx">MISSION</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem class="has-sub" Value="#">LEADERSHIP
        <asp:BulletedList ID="bListMenuSub" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
            <asp:ListItem Value="#">President</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="#">Medical Director</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="#">Board of Directors</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="#">Key Administrators</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="history.aspx">HISTORY</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="community_support.aspx">COMMUNITY SUPPORT</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

When I visit the page, i get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects.

Source Error:


Line 9:                 <asp:ListItem Value="#">Board of Directors</asp:ListItem>
Line 10:                <asp:ListItem Value="#">Key Administrators</asp:ListItem>
Line 11:            </asp:BulletedList>
Line 12:        </asp:ListItem>
Line 13:        <asp:ListItem Value="history.aspx">HISTORY</asp:ListItem>


Source File: /website/includeNav/aboutUsNav.inc    Line: 11
```

Comment: We will be adding the page to our CMS and allow other users to edit. Having the ASP control will allow the CMS to allow the users to edit without a webmaster being present.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700632/how-to-create-a-nested-bulleted-list

Comment: That adds the items as menu and my CSS codes are designed to work with UL/LI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you can read from [BulletedList Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the BulletedList control can display list items as any of the following:

- Static text   The text displayed by the control is not interactive.
- T:System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink controls   Users can click links to navigate to another page. You must provide a target URL as the Value property of individual items.
- LinkButton controls   Users can click individual items and the control performs a postback.

Anyway you can easily achieve your task, using instead a common repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" EnableViewState="False" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myItemDataBound">
 <HeaderTemplate>
   <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <li><%# Eval("nome") %>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="bulletedList" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>
      </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
      </ul>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And populate the bulletedList in ItemDataBound event:

```
protected void myItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (null == row)
        return;

    DataSet1.table1Row currentRow = row.Row as DataSet1.table1Row ;

    if (currentRow != null)
    {
        BulletedList bList = e.Item.FindControl("bulletedList") as BulletedList;

        bList.Items.Add("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: So from the top code, keep adding each LI and in the code add each sub bulleted list? The `Eval("nome")` will be replaced by what I want right?

Comment: The Eval("nome") keep the value from you datasource and will be replaced, the you must fill your inner bulletlist with your logic

Comment: What assembler directive do I have to import in my .CS page?

Comment: system.web.ui.webcontrols is the assembly of all webcontrols

Comment: I do have that loading in my .CS page

Comment: What if I don't want to use a DataSet because it's all static list?

Comment: you can bind your repeater with a list<ofwhatyouwant>

Comment: You mean this line: `DataSet1.table1Row currentRow = row.Row as DataSet1.table1Row;`

Comment: What i mean is that you can bind yous repeaters with collections